# Likelihood of polynomial time series

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, econometrics, stochastic-processes

I want to model a time series process as follows:

There are a total of T periods. I want to model audience dynamics. There is an initial audience of $N_0$ that evolves over minutes indexed by  $t$.
Each period is characterized by a binary state (R(ed), B(lue)) with an indicator function $f_t^R = 1 \quad \text{if} \quad t$ is $R$. The probability of staying is $\alpha_R , \alpha_B$ for each type of minute; respectively. Now, the stochastic process comes because, randomly, people enter the process from outside ($\mu_t>0)$:

$N_t=N_{t-1}(\alpha_Rf_t^R + \alpha_Bf^B_t) + \mu_t$

which, iteratively yields:

$N_t= N_0 \left( \alpha_R^{\sum_{j=1}^t f^R_j} \times \alpha_B^{\sum_{j=1}^tf^B_j}\right) + \sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\mu_j\left( \alpha_R^{\sum_{h=j}^{t-1} f^R_h} \times \alpha_B^{\sum_{h=j}^{t-1}f^B_h}\right) + \mu_t$

Ideally, I'm trying to develop the likelihood function (since I actually have a panel and not just time series). Is there any way to derive it? Importantly, I can't really rely on large sample asymptotic on t since minutes are fixed and rather small (I focus on 30 minutes day after day).